# Ubuntu Server VPS pauses randomly

Tags: server, ssh, python, vps

I run a discord bot written in python that I recently moved to a VPS service. It ran great on my own local server until I moved it to the VPS. The script runs on python and over the last few months it will randomly freeze up for 20-50 mins and the bot will appear to be offline from discord and not take any commands. The python script should say whenever it goes offline but during those freezes it doesn't log it going offline (which it normally does if discord or the server goes offline). Memory and CPU usage are always at less than 1-5% usage and never spike so I don't think it has anything to do with the script overloading the vps.

If I ssh into the VPS while it's frozen, it will unfreeze itself immediately and the bot will go back online as if nothing happened with no trace of it going offline in my python script. I also use screen so that I can run the python script while I'm not logged in thru ssh.

This usually happens during non peak hours so I have a feeling that it might have to do something with Ubuntu sleeping/hibernating? Not sure, it never happened on my local ubuntu server.

Comment: When Ubuntu Desktop sleeps/resumes, it logs the activity in /var/log/syslog. Ubuntu Server does not sleep by default for obvious reasons.